# Why is my Json string response escaped for a WCF Rest web service (weakly-typed Json) response?

Tags: c#, .net, json, rest, wcf

I have this contract :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceJsonContract
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/MyMethod", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
    Message MyMethod(Message input);
}
```

And the definition for MyMethod is :

```
Message MyMethod(Message input)
{
...
Message response = Message.CreateMessage(
                                 MessageVersion.None,
                                 "*",
                                 "{\"bla\": 2 }", 
                                 new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string)));

response.Properties.Add( WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name,new 
WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json)); 

var contextOutgoingResponse = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
contextOutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";

return response;
}
```

When calling the method I got the Json escaped:

"{\"bla\": 2 }"

instead of unescaped one (below):

"{"bla": 2 }"

Any idea how to get the unescaped Json (  "{"bla": 2 }"  ) ?

Thanks

Comment: You should pass a dictionary or object instead of building your own JSON.

Comment: Thanks , SLaks . Can you provide a short example ?(in my case I have a string and DataContractJsonSerializer is string also but this escapes the response

Answer (score 0):

The DataContractJsonSerializer is serializing your string and escaping the quotation marks. Create a class to hold your data and pass that instead of the string.

```
public class MyData 
{
    public string Bla { get; set; } 
}

// create an instance
MyData myData = new MyData()
{
    Bla = "the value";
};   

// then use it
Message response = Message.CreateMessage(
                             MessageVersion.None,
                             "*",
                             myData, 
                             new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyData)));
```

Comment: Thanks , but I have weakly-typed Json , This means the Json response cannot by typed (using a class ) . I have the response on a string , I just don't know how to send it back to the sender unescaped

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Stream` as your out put. this way you can send back uncapped string:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServiceJsonContract
    {
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/MyMethod", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
        Stream MyMethod(Message input);
    }

Stream MyMethod(Message input)
{
..
return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"bla\": 2 }"));
}
```

Comment: I know this option , David , and it works , thanks a lot . Is what I'm using now . However , when I deploy the web service I had an error . complaining that if I have the Message as a parameter I need to have Message also as response (I was trying to expose the web service using 2 endpoints , json and soap) . I end up creating 2 web services ,a soap and a json one . The Json has the definition exactly as yours  (but it will be nice to return as Message , to have only one web service eventually)

Comment: you are welcome dear @Cezar. unfortunately you cant have both restful and soap service like this.

Comment: This is the error when you try to get the wsdl :an exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension: DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
 contract: http://tempuri.org/:IServiceJsonContract ----> System.InvalidOperationException:The operation 'MyMethod' could not be loaded because it has a parameter or return type of type System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or a type that has MessageContractAttribute and other parameters of different types. When using System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or types with MessageContractAttribute,the method must not use any other types of parameters.